# Audio Analysis tools CLI

Tags: windows, audio, command-line

What graphs / visuals can be generated from audio files?
Is there a command-line utility to generate said visual?

I found the following:

Waveform : ffmpeg is able to generate a waveform
Spectrogram : sox can make a spectrogram

Any CLI tool for audio analysis could be useful as well.
Basically anything that'll give me more information than
duration, bitrate, format, channels, sample rate, bit/sample.

My operating system is Windows 7.
Solutions for other platforms are accepted.
(just precise what os the solution is aimed at)

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't tried it myself [pyAudioAnalysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis) to quote the blurb:

pyAudioAnalysis is a Python library covering a wide range of audio analysis tasks. Through pyAudioAnalysis you can:

- Extract audio features and representations (e.g. mfccs, spectrogram, chromagram)
- Classify unknown sounds
- Train, parameter tune and evaluate classifiers of audio segments
- Detect audio events and exclude silence periods from long recordings
- Perform supervised segmentation (joint segmentation - classification)
- Perform unsupervised segmentation (e.g. speaker diarization)
- Extract audio thumbnails
- Train and use audio regression models (example application: emotion recognition)
- Apply dimensionality reduction to visualize audio data and content similarities
- ***Command Line Operation*** e.g.:

  - Chromagram extraction: `python audioAnalysis.py fileChromagram -i data/doremi.wav`.
    [image: Example 1]

Note that there are many, (446 at the time of writing), forks of this code on github some of which may include useful modifications.

Pre-Requisites:

- git version control client, *(several clients are readily available for just about every platform)*.
- [python](https://www.python.org) (the original code is for python 2.7 but at least part of [this](https://github.com/naktinis/pyAudioAnalysis) fork run under python 3.3 or later).
- Several python packages, running `pip install numpy matplotlib scipy sklearn hmmlearn simplejson eyed3 pydub` after installing python should do the job.

Examples and detailed tutorials can be found at the [wiki](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/wiki).

This option is Free, (Gratis & Open Source), and cross platform.

Comment: Neat! I'll definitely be looking into it.